# Recovering data from NTFS file system

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, ntfs, lvm, lvm2

I have a hard drive with lvm2 pv file system. Its a 2TB drive from the NAS. I believe its partition table is damaged. There for I am going to format it with NTFS file system. Is there any problem in data recovery if I convert from lvm2 pv to ntfs ? What I am planning to do is convert the partition to NTFS from LVM2 PV and then recover the data from windows os using any data recovery tool. Changing the file system will make issues in data recovery ? Or do I have to use lvm2 pv again and recover from that ?

Comment: Converting damaged filesystem will add errors (if it can be performed at all). Anycase - make a raw (sector-by-sector) copy or this drive content, then try everything what you can.

Comment: @Akina Its a 2TB drive. I don't have a backup drive. I am planning upload my file to zoolz cloud. What are the chances of loosing files from drive ..? Only partition table is missing.

Comment: *I don't have a backup drive.* If so prevent ANY write to this drive (including hidden) - use only euristic recovery software which recovers data to another drive. Remember - each byte changed on this drive decreases successfull recovery probability.

Comment: @Akina Will not be going to write any data to the same disk. Just the recovery and temporary move some files to another 1TB (laptop disk) and then slowly uploading to cloud.